# File Upload Failure by Jersey 2.0 Client

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to implement REST Client for Dropbox with Jersey 2.0.

In order to upload files, I use following code:

```
WebTarget target = client.target(targetUrl);
final FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
final MultiPart multipart = new FormDataMultiPart().bodyPart(filePart);
Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).put(Entity.entity(multipart, multipart.getMediaType()));
```

However, this code does not work and `MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException` occurs in the `put` method.

How can I avoid the `MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException` in the `put` method.

Here's stack trace when the exception occurred:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=multipart/form-data, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1005)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:430)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:634)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:631)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:421)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:631)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.put(JerseyInvocation.java:285)
    at com.clouddrive.dropbox.DropBoxController.uploadFile(DropBoxController.java:161)
    at com.clouddrive.util.WatchDir.processEvents(WatchDir.java:200)
    at com.clouddrive.CloudDrive.main(CloudDrive.java:111)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 12):

I modified initialization code and confirmed that the code work correctly.

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
            .build();
```

I apologize for the inconvenience.